odd behavior changing dir from .xonshrc
I am using the xonsh shell and my .xonshrc file contains a call to os.chdir(), which works, but oddly.  When I start xonsh, my prompt, which shows my current path, seems to indicate I am still in my home dir until after I execute a command or even simply press enter.  e.g.
[etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p ~]$ export PROCESS=ibmc_reminder; /etlsmart/env/xonsh/bin/xonsh
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:~
$
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:/etlsmart/feeds/ibmc_reminder
$


If I execute a command such as ls, it lists the contents of the correct directory (the one I've changed to, not my home directory).
[etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p ~]$ export PROCESS=ibmc_reminder; /etlsmart/env/xonsh/bin/xonsh
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:~
$ ls
bin  block  data  docs  etc  lock  log  post_deployment  stage
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:/etlsmart/feeds/ibmc_reminder
$ ls
bin  block  data  docs  etc  lock  log  post_deployment  stage


So this appears to be a benign cosmetic problem.  That is, unless my first command is cd, then it does not behave correctly.  The cd neither fails nor works, which makes no sense to me.
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:~
$ cd log
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:/etlsmart/feeds/ibmc_reminder
$ pwd
/etlsmart/feeds/ibmc_reminder
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:/etlsmart/feeds/ibmc_reminder
$ cd log
etlsmart@msd-cld-etl-21p:/etlsmart/feeds/ibmc_reminder/log

I have tried adding various commands to my .xonshrc file to get past this, but so far without success.  Can anyone offer an explanation and/or solution to this problem?

It will be good to do this after init. This works to me in ~/.xonshrc:
@events.on_post_init
def on_post_init(**_):
    cd /tmp

But I see that xontrib-back2dir and xontrib-jump-to-dir use another approach:
@events.on_post_init
def on_post_init(**_):
  __xonsh__.subproc_captured_stdout(['cd', '/tmp'])


Thanks, that worked.  But it also showed me what the fundamental problem was.  os.chdir was causing this strangeness.  using cd instead, as you did, it behaved as expected.
